# Compilation Error in C program in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, project, codeblocks

I intend to use a C program which would povide Banking Services including

1. Adding a Bank Account
2. Update Information of existing account
3. Viewing a Customer's past transactions
4. Viewing details of an account
5. Deleting a Customer's Account
6. Viewing existing accounts

For this I have made functions to be called at appropriate places namely(in order of service listed above),

menu() – This function displays the menu or welcome screen to perform different banking activities mentioned below.

new_acc() – This function creates a new customer account. It asks for some  personal and banking details of the customer such as name, date of birth, citizenship number, address and phone number. You can enter the amount to deposit and choose one type of deposit account – saving, current, fixed for 1 year, fixed for 2 years or fixed for 3 years.

view list() – With this function, you can view the customer’s banking information such as account number, name, address and phone number provided while creating the account.

edit() – This function has been used for changing the address and phone number of a particular customer account.

transact() – With this function, you can deposit and withdraw money to and from a particular customer account.

erase() – This function is for deleting a customer account.

see() – This function shows account number, name, date of birth, citizenship number, age, address, phone number, type of account, amount deposited and date of deposit. It also displays the amount of interest corresponding to a particular account type.

File handling has been used for almost all functions. File has been used to store data related to new account, transaction, editing of account information and viewing of account information. I haven’t used file handling for the menu, interest calculation and password.
NOTE: Password to access the program is *g5rox*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main_exit;
void menu();
struct date
    {
        int month,day,year;
    };
struct {

    char name;
    int acc_no,age;
    char address[60];
    char aadhar[12];
    double phone[10];
    char acc_type[10];
    float amt;
    struct date dob;
    struct date deposit;
    struct date withdraw;

    }add,upd,check,rem,transaction;

float interest(float t,float amount,int rate)
{
    float SI;
    SI=(rate*t*amount)/100.0;
    return (SI);

}
void fordelay(int j)
{   int i,k;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
         k=i;
}

void new_acc()
{
    int choice;
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr=fopen("record.dat","a+");
    account_no:
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\t\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 ADD RECORD \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");
    printf("\n\n\nEnter today's date(mm/dd/yyyy):");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&add.deposit.month,&add.deposit.day,&add.deposit.year);
    printf("\nEnter your #Account number:");
    scanf("%d",&check.acc_no);
    while(fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
    {
        if (check.acc_no==add.acc_no)
            {printf("Sorry, Account no. already in use!");
            fordelay(1000000000);
                goto account_no;

            }
    }
    add.acc_no=check.acc_no;
    printf("\nEnter your #Name:");
    scanf("%s",&add.name);
    printf("\nEnter the #DateOfBirth(mm/dd/yyyy):");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&add.dob.month,&add.dob.day,&add.dob.year);
    printf("\nEnter the #Age:");
    scanf("%d",&add.age);
    printf("\nEnter the #Address:");
    scanf("%s",&add.address);
    printf("\nEnter your #Aadhar number:");
    scanf("%s",&add.aadhar[12]);
    printf("\nEnter the #Mobile number: ");
    scanf("%lf",&add.phone);
    printf("\nEnter the #Amount to deposit:Rs");
    scanf("%f",&add.amt);
    printf("\nType of account:\n\t#Saving\n\t#Current\n\t#Fixed1(for 1 year)\n\t#Fixed2(for 2 years)\n\t#Fixed3(for 3 years)\n\n\tEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%s",&add.acc_type);
//
    fprintf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
    fclose(ptr);
    printf("\nKudos! Account created successfully!");
    add_invalid:
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
    scanf("%d",&main_exit);
    system("cls");
    if (main_exit==1)
        menu();
    else if(main_exit==0)
            close();
    else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid!\a");
            goto add_invalid;
        }
}
void view_list()
{
    FILE *view;
    view=fopen("record.dat","r");
    int test=0;
    system("cls");
    printf("\nACC. NO.\tNAME\t\t\tADDRESS\t\t\tPHONE\n");

    while(fscanf(view,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
       {
           printf("\n%6d\t %10s\t\t\t%10s\t\t%.0lf",add.acc_no,add.name,add.address,add.phone);
           test++;
       }

    fclose(view);
    if (test==0)
        {   system("cls");
            printf("\nNO RECORDS!!\n");}

    view_list_invalid:
     printf("\n\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
        scanf("%d",&main_exit);
        system("cls");
        if (main_exit==1)
            menu();
        else if(main_exit==0)
            close();
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid!\a");
            goto view_list_invalid;
        }
}
void edit(void)
{
    int choice,test=0;
    FILE *old,*newrec;
    old=fopen("record.dat","r");
    newrec=fopen("new.dat","w");

    printf("\nEnter the account no. of the customer whose info you want to change:");
    scanf("%d",&upd.acc_no);
    while(fscanf(old,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,&add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
    {
        if (add.acc_no==upd.acc_no)
        {   test=1;
            printf("\nWhat information do you want to change?\n1.Address\n2.Phone\n\nEnter your choice(1 for address and 2 for phone):");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            system("cls");
            if(choice==1)
                {printf("Enter the new address:");
                scanf("%s",upd.address);
                fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,upd.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                system("cls");
                printf("Changes saved!");
                }
            else if(choice==2)
                {
                    printf("Enter the new phone number:");
                scanf("%lf",&upd.phone);
                fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,upd.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                system("cls");
                printf("Changes saved!");
                }

        }
        else
            fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
    }
    fclose(old);
    fclose(newrec);
    remove("record.dat");
    rename("new.dat","record.dat");

if(test!=1)
        {   system("cls");
            printf("\nSorry, Record not found!!\a\a\a");
            edit_invalid:
              printf("\nEnter 0 to try again,1 to return to main menu and 2 to exit:");
              scanf("%d",&main_exit);
              system("cls");
                 if (main_exit==1)

                    menu();
                else if (main_exit==2)
                    close();
                else if(main_exit==0)
                    edit();
                else
                    {printf("\nInvalid!\a");
                    goto edit_invalid;}
        }
    else
        {printf("\n\n\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
        scanf("%d",&main_exit);
        system("cls");
        if (main_exit==1)
            menu();
        else
            close();
        }
}

void transact(void)
{   int choice,test=0;
    FILE *old,*newrec;
    old=fopen("record.dat","r");
    newrec=fopen("new.dat","w");

        printf("Enter the account no. :");
    scanf("%d",&transaction.acc_no);
    while (fscanf(old,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
   {

            if(add.acc_no==transaction.acc_no)
            {   test=1;
                if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed1")==0||strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed2")==0||strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed3")==0)
                {
                    printf("\a\a\a\n\nSorry, but YOU CANNOT DEPOSIT OR WITHDRAW CASH IN FIXED ACCOUNTS!!!!!");
                    fordelay(1000000000);
                    system("cls");
                    menu();

                }
                printf("\n\nDo you want to\n1.Deposit\n2.Withdraw?\n\nEnter your choice(1 for deposit and 2 for withdraw):");
                scanf("%d",&choice);
                if (choice==1)
                {
                    printf("Enter the amount you want to deposit:Rs ");
                    scanf("%f",&transaction.amt);
                    add.amt+=transaction.amt;
                    fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                    printf("\n\nKudos! Deposited successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Enter the amount you want to withdraw:Rs ");
                    scanf("%f",&transaction.amt);
                    add.amt-=transaction.amt;
                    fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                    printf("\n\nKudos! Withdrawn successfully!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
               fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
            }
   }
   fclose(old);
   fclose(newrec);
   remove("record.dat");
   rename("new.dat","record.dat");
   if(test!=1)
   {
       printf("\n\nSorry, Record not found!!");
       transact_invalid:
      printf("\n\n\nEnter 0 to try again,1 to return to main menu and 2 to exit:");
      scanf("%d",&main_exit);
      system("cls");
      if (main_exit==0)
        transact();
    else if (main_exit==1)
        menu();
    else if (main_exit==2)
        close();
    else
    {
        printf("\nInvalid!");
        goto transact_invalid;
    }

   }
   else
   {
       printf("\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
        scanf("%d",&main_exit);
        system("cls");
        if (main_exit==1)
            menu();
        else
            close();
   }

}
void erase(void)
{
    FILE *old,*newrec;
    int test=0;
    old=fopen("record.dat","r");
    newrec=fopen("new.dat","w");
    printf("Enter the #account_no. you want to delete:");
    scanf("%d",&rem.acc_no);
    while (fscanf(old,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
   {
        if(add.acc_no!=rem.acc_no)
            fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);

        else
            {test++;
            printf("\nKudos! Record deleted successfully!\n");
            }
   }
   fclose(old);
   fclose(newrec);
   remove("record.dat");
   rename("new.dat","record.dat");
   if(test==0)
        {
            printf("\nSorry, Record not found!!\a\a\a");
            erase_invalid:
              printf("\nEnter 0 to try again,1 to return to main menu and 2 to exit:");
              scanf("%d",&main_exit);

                 if (main_exit==1)
                    menu();
                else if (main_exit==2)
                    close();
                else if(main_exit==0)
                    erase();
                else
                    {printf("\nInvalid!\a");
                    goto erase_invalid;}
        }
    else
        {printf("\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
        scanf("%d",&main_exit);
        system("cls");
        if (main_exit==1)
            menu();
        else
            close();
        }

}

void see(void)
{
    FILE *ptr;
    int test=0,rate;
    int choice;
    float time;
    float intrst;
    ptr=fopen("record.dat","r");
    printf("Do you want to check with\n#1 Account no\n#2 Name\nEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if (choice==1)
    {   printf("Enter the #account_number:");
        scanf("%d",&check.acc_no);

        while (fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
        {
            if(add.acc_no==check.acc_no)
            {   system("cls");
                test=1;

                printf("\n#Account NO.:%d\n#Name:%s \n#DOB:%d/%d/%d \n#Age:%d \n#Address:%s \n#Aadhar No:%s \n#Phone number:%.0lf \n#Type Of Account:%s \n#Amount deposited:$ %.2f \n#Date Of Deposit:%d/%d/%d\n\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,
                add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed1")==0)
                    {
                        time=1.0;
                        rate=9;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+1);
                    }
                else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed2")==0)
                    {
                        time=2.0;
                        rate=11;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+2);

                    }
                else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed3")==0)
                    {
                        time=3.0;
                        rate=13;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+3);

                    }
                 else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"saving")==0)
                    {
                        time=(1.0/12.0);
                        rate=8;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d of every month. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.day);

                     }
                 else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"current")==0)
                    {

                        printf("\n\nSorry, You will get no interest.\a\a");

                     }

            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice==2)
    {   printf("Enter the #name:");
        scanf("%s",&check.name);
        while (fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
        {
            if(strcmpi(add.name,check.name)==0)
            {   system("cls");
                test=1;
                printf("\n#Account No.:%d\n#Name:%s \n#DOB:%d/%d/%d \n#Age:%d \n#Address:%s \n#Aadhar No:%s \n#Phone number:%.0lf \n#Type Of Account:%s \n#Amount deposited:$%.2f \n#Date Of Deposit:%d/%d/%d\n\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.aadhar,add.phone,
                add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
                if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed1")==0)
                    {
                        time=1.0;
                        rate=9;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+1);
                    }
                else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed2")==0)
                    {
                        time=2.0;
                        rate=11;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+2);

                    }
                else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed3")==0)
                    {
                        time=3.0;
                        rate=13;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+3);

                    }
                 else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"saving")==0)
                    {
                        time=(1.0/12.0);
                        rate=8;
                        intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                        printf("\n\n You will get $.%.2f as interest on %d of every month. Cheers!",intrst,add.deposit.day);

                     }
                 else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"current")==0)
                    {

                        printf("\n\nSorry, You will get no interest\a\a");

                     }

            }
        }
    }


    fclose(ptr);
     if(test!=1)
        {   system("cls");
            printf("\nRecord not found!! Please Check again\a\a\a");
            see_invalid:
              printf("\nEnter 0 to try again,1 to return to main menu and 2 to exit:");
              scanf("%d",&main_exit);
              system("cls");
                 if (main_exit==1)
                    menu();
                else if (main_exit==2)
                    close();
                else if(main_exit==0)
                    see();
                else
                    {
                        system("cls");
                        printf("\nInvalid!\a");
                        goto see_invalid;}
        }
    else
        {printf("\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
        scanf("%d",&main_exit);}
        if (main_exit==1)
        {
            system("cls");
            menu();
        }

        else
           {

             system("cls");
            close();
            }

}


void close(void)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\nThis Program is developed by Group#5|C1");
    }


void menu(void)
{   int choice;
    system("cls");
    system("color 2");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tVISHWAKARMA BANKING SERVICES");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 >| WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU |< \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");
    printf("\n\n\t\t1.Create new account\n\t\t2.Update information of existing account\n\t\t3.For transactions\n\t\t4.Check the details of existing account\n\t\t5.Removing existing account\n\t\t6.View customer's list\n\t\t7.Exit\n\n\n\n\n\t\t Enter your choice:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    system("cls");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:new_acc();
        break;
        case 2:edit();
        break;
        case 3:transact();
        break;
        case 4:see();
        break;
        case 5:erase();
        break;
        case 6:view_list();
        break;
        case 7:close();
        break;

    }



}
int main()
{
    char pass[10],password[10]="g5rox";
    int i=0;
    printf("\n\n\t\tEnter the #password to login:");
    scanf("%s",pass);

    if (strcmp(pass,password)==0)
        {printf("\n\nPassword Match!\n\n\nLoading Program");
        for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
        {
            fordelay(100000000);
            printf(".");
        }
                system("cls");
            menu();
        }
    else
        {   printf("\n\nOops! Wrong password!!\a\a\a");
            login_try:
            printf("\nEnter 1 to try again and 0 to exit:");
            scanf("%d",&main_exit);
            if (main_exit==1)
                    {

                        system("cls");
                        main();
                    }

            else if (main_exit==0)
                    {
                    system("cls");
                    close();}
            else
                    {printf("\nInvalid!");
                    fordelay(1000000000);
                    system("cls");
                    goto login_try;}

        }
        return 0;
}
```

This program gives an compilation error in the midst when using any one of the services without providing any reason. I am unable to understand it either.

[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhB68.png)

A Detailed Soultion would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget the ***minimal*** part of your [mcve]. Or telling us the errors you get.

Comment: That's not a compilation error, it's a runtime error. Probably some form of Undefined Behaviour (check buffer overflow, dangling pointer, `NULL` dereference). Also up the warning level of your compiler; sometimes the compiler can catch the error.

Comment: And after a quick glance at the much to large code you currently show, I would argue that whatever resource you're using to learn C you should throw it away as it's so full of bad habits and bad code.

Comment: A debugger is the right tool to find a runtime error. You can easily find where the crash is and examine the variables and call stack to figure out why it happened.

Comment: @SomeprogrammerdudeI realize your straightforwardness, but it would be real good if you mention specifically the ways/parts of the code I have written badly.

Comment: Global variables, especially the `i` and`j` variables which (if used for loops) should be defined for the loops themselves). You also shadow some of these variable locally inside functions. The `fordelay` function which is very unreliable (you include `<windows.h>` so you should have access to the Windows [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) function). General lack of documentation or comments. Copious use of labels and `goto` instead of loop. Possible infinite recursive call of the `menu` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write this:

> ```
> while(fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d\n",&add.acc_no,add.name,&add.dob.month,&add.dob.day,&add.dob.year,&add.age,add.address,add.citizenship,&add.phone,add.acc_type,&add.amt,&add.deposit.month,&add.deposit.day,&add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
> {
>     //...
> }
> ```

If `fscanf()` returns `EOF` that means the operation encountered an error, so your loop is terminated only when reading triggers an error.

Attempting to read `"foobar"` into an `int` variable **is not** an error, it's a matching failure.

-- added example ----

Eg... when the input buffer contains something other than a digit, this is an infinite loop

```
// assume input buffer contains "14/42\n"
unsigned sum = 0, i, j;
while (scanf("%u%u", &i, &j) != EOF) {
    sum += i + j;
}
```

The first time through the loop, `scanf()` assigns `14` to `i`, meets the slash in input which triggers a matching failure and so returns with value `1`. `1` is not `EOF` so the body of the loop executes (`j` is still unininitialized!!!) and the loop repeat with `"/42"` in the input buffer.

The 2nd time through the loop, the matching failure occurs with the very first character `scanf()` sees: the slash is not a valid character for `"%u"` so scanf return a value of `0`. `0` is not `EOF` so the loop goes on forever.

Reading with `fgets()` consumes all of the input

```
char buf[100]; // large enough
unsigned sum = 0, i, j;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    // if (parse(buf, &i, &j) == 0) {
    //     sum += i + j;
    // } else {
    //     printf(stderr, "error in input\n");
    // }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: get user-input (file input too, not just keyboard) with `fgets()` and write code to parse the line read. `fgets()` is much much more well-suited to error management in input operations. Basically `while (fgets(...) != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: Not allowed in the input format, but thanks for sharing!